# Display dates with comma separation

Tags: mysql, date-format

I have these 2 Tables.

```
Emp 
    id       name 
    01      Sten
    02      Willam


Customer

    id    name    date_entered     visited_by_Emp_id
    1     Reon     2011-12-11               1
    2     Reon     2011-12-13               1
    3     Samy     2012-01-02               2
    4     Samy     2012-01-05               2
    5     Samy    2012-02-07                2
```

Now I want to display dates with comma separated like

My output should be

```
Customer_Name    YEAR     Jan    Feb     Mar      Apr      Jun........ up to    Dec
  Samy           2012    02,05    07                                                 

  Reon           2011                                                          11,13
```

"So I just want to ask that how can I display these dates with comma separation",
Any  suggestions will be helpful

Comment: **[What have you tried so far??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  e.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(MONTH(date_entered) = 1, DAYOFMONTH(date_entered), NULL)) Jan,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(MONTH(date_entered) = 2, DAYOFMONTH(date_entered), NULL)) Feb,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(MONTH(date_entered) = 3, DAYOFMONTH(date_entered), NULL)) Mar
FROM emp e
  JOIN customer c
    ON e.id = c.visited_by_Emp_id
GROUP BY e.id, YEAR(date_entered)
```